# Getting the Delta between the rows on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the difference between the row on the same column. I can use lag()over but how can I get the result like the pic, if the name changed then start counting as new

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (call_received - 
        lag(call_received, 1, 0) over (partition by agent_name order by id)
       ) as delta
from t;
```

Note that this uses the rarely seen three-argument form of `lag()`.

Comment: this is big help. it is working well on my result. thanks